# I get a error if I try to call each other's classes in each other's files in Typescript

Tags: typescript

**I want to instansiate each other's classes in the each other's classes. But I get this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at GamePanel.js:2:23"
here is the each code inside of each file**
I can't do like this???

```
import {Player} from "./Player";
export class GamePanel{

    canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
    c: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    count: number = 0;
    public player:Player = new Player(this);

    constructor(){
        this.canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.querySelector("canvas");
        const c = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        
        if(!c){
            throw new Error("failed");
        }

        this.c = c;

        
    }
```

```
import { GamePanel } from "./GamePanel";
export class Player{
    gp: GamePanel;

    constructor(gp:GamePanel){
        this.gp = gp;
        
    }   

    public draw(c:CanvasRenderingContext2D):void{
        c.fillStyle = "red";
        c.fillRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
        console.log("appeared");
        let image = new Image;
        image.src = "../img/down.png";
        c.drawImage(image, 300,300,100,100);
        c.drawImage(image, 300,400,100,100);


    }
}
```

**both files are inside of same folder**

---

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! I'm pretty sure your problem is that the Typescript compiler thinks you are trying to run your code in CommonJS (Node modules) instead of browser modules. Try adding this to `package.json`: `"type": "module"`

Comment: You also have a circular dependency

Comment: I added "type":"module". but error messsage didn't change.